# p:photocam disable warnings

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using photocam from Primefaces to capture a simple photo.

When a computer that has no webcam access the web page, an error

> "Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam."

shows up. Is it possible to supress this warning when the computer does not have a webcam? How can I do it?

I am using Java, a Web Maven Project with JSF and primefaces 6.0.

Comment: Look in the source of webcam.js in the primefaces github. Find the location, override the function and wrap in a try-catch

Comment: @Kukeltje I found the location in the js file. But i cannot edit the file via NetBeans, do I need to go to the local Maven Repository? What if I re-import primefaces, will the change be overwritten?

Comment: Override like you would override any existing javascript. Many options. Google is your friend. To 'unrelated' and time-consuming for me to write a 'solution' for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to edit the js file related to photocam (`photocam.js`).

To do that, I used 7-zip to access the file (inside `Primefaces` jar, `Maven Repository`) and extracted it.

After the extraction and the modifications, I replaced the older file.

The modification was to return null instead of the error message.

Comment: How did you replace the older file and how did you generate a new .jar file?

Comment: @mucisk Actually, I didn't generated a new .jar. I used 7-zip and first extracted the file photocam.js from inside the primefaces .jar. Then, after modifying it, i just "dragged and dropped" the modified photocam.js inside the same .jar file (using 7-zip GUI), substituting the old one. I think you could just copy the original .jar file and modificate it, ensuring that if you mess up with anything you have a backup.